# Firebase notification in Phonegap Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add notifications to my app in PhoneGap.
For that, I'm using this plugin (https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm).

This seems to work. When I add a notification in firebase, I get it in the phone with the parameters I have set.

Now I'm trying to get the parameters when the user entered into the app through a notification to take an special action with that data.

According the the documentation in the link above, I should add this event:

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(
    function(data){
        if(data.wasTapped)
            //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
            alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
        }else{
            //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
            alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
        }
    },
    function(msg){
        console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
    }
);
```

However, no alert is displayed. And I don't find any way to debug it, since it only runs in mobile (not even emulated, only real one).

Something seems wrong? I only need for android.
Also I'm including that event in the `bindEvents` when the app is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. But I had used this plugin [firebase-plugin](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) and made changes in these files

FirebasePluginMessagingService.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.firebase;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.searchtrade.demo.MainActivity;

import java.util.Map;


public class FirebasePluginMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FirebasePlugin";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    String title = null;
    String text = null;
    String category = null;


    int id = 0;
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        text = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    } else {
        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        text = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");
        category = remoteMessage.getData().get("category");
        try {
            id = Integer.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("id"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Title: " + title);
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body/Text: " + text);

    Log.d(TAG, "myNewMessageBody: " + title);
    // TODO: Add option to developer to configure if show notification when app on foreground
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        sendNotification(id, title, text, category,remoteMessage.getData());
     }

}

private void sendNotification(int id, String title, String messageBody,String category, Map<String, String> data) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnNotificationOpenReceiver.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        bundle.putString(key, data.get(key));
    }
    bundle.putString("myTitle",title);
    bundle.putString("myMessageBody",messageBody);
    bundle.putString("myCategory",category); // additional payload data

    Log.d(TAG, "myMessageBody: " + messageBody);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
}


}
```

OnNotificationOpenReceiver.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.firebase;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnNotificationOpenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String title,text,category;
private static final String TAG = "BroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // Toast.makeText(context,"test6",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent i = new Intent(context, CustomLaunchUrl.class);

    ///////////////
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //////////////
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    title = data.getString("myTitle");
    text = data.getString("myMessageBody");
    category = data.getString("myCategory");
    Bundle dt = new Bundle();
    dt.putString("finalTitle",title);
    dt.putString("finalBody",text);
    dt.putString("finalCategory",category);
    i.putExtras(dt);
    Log.d(TAG,"Notification working test: ");
  //  Toast.makeText(context,title+"    "+text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    context.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

Adding new file for custom page launch with custom function

CustomLaunchUrl.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.firebase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;


public class CustomLaunchUrl extends CordovaActivity {

String x,y,z;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // load the layout

    Bundle d = getIntent().getExtras();
    x = d.getString("finalTitle");
    y = d.getString("finalBody");
    z = d.getString("finalCategory");
    //Toast.makeText(CustomLaunchUrl.this, x+"   "+y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/networkStats_2.html"); // change html as your need
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
            loadUrl("javascript:set_ndata('"+x+"','"+y+"','"+z+"')");
        }
    }, 2000);
}
}
```

Add this in Platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.CustomLaunchUrl">
    </activity>
```

And in your www/networkStats_2.html add this function

```
function set_ndata(x,y,z)  //got payload data in html page
{
  alert(x);
  alert(y);
  alert(z);
}
```

Comment: Just put that file in firebase plugin folder. And after making changes in java files you need to remove and add android platform. And then you can build the app with effective changes.

Comment: I just removed my comment my question because I thought it was stupid :D

Comment: I am not sure if I am suing it correctly, dynamic links just try to open in google chrome instead of the app https://firebaselink/?link=file:///android_asset/www/networkStats_2.html&apn=packgeID

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. But native plugins only works on their device. In this case which is android.

Comment: I talked with you on firebase plugin git hub, my issue with about redirecting dynamic links and you said to check this answer

Comment: I am not sure how to use it now, and yes I am testing on android

Comment: Ok. I am doing the same in this answer. Just read the answer carefully also the comments in the code. U will get the solution.

Comment: Are you trying open app's specific page in your mobile web browser ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125213/discussion-between-zahema-and-shahbaz-hashmi).