# How to enable firebase foreground push notification in cordova?

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm able to receive the notification in the background when the app is closed, but when the application is open I'm getting the message from firebase in the backend, but it's not getting fired.

```
Emulator Console: View not ready. SAVED NOTIFICATION: javascript:FCMPlugin.onNotificationReceived(xxxxxxxx).

//Function to fire notification
 window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
        alert("Notification Received"+ JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(notification)));


    }, function(error) {});
```

Comment: Working code with custom changes. No need to change anything else https://stackoverflow.com/a/39873647/4685284